# Bad request on form submissions

Tags: multi-site

Could my sudden bad requests on form submissions be linked to defaultCookieDomain
and multi site use with separate add on domain?

We added defaultCookieDomain as live preview wasn't working - didnt fix it by the way - but our add on domin is obviously the same. Can we just leave it blank?

Comment: Is your `{{ csrfInput() }}` wrapped in a cache tag?

Comment: No i dont think so but good call! but my cookie settings were for one domain only and config CRSF was true